# TYPO3: Is it possible to include links in a description with the bullets list component?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Using Typo3 8.7.19, and I was asked to include a set of links to documents/videos inside a page, so I thought about a description list. Each title would be the title of the link(s), and the description the actual links that should be rendered as

```
<a href="http://something.linky" rel="noopener noreferrer">http://something.linky</a>
```

So all the thing should become something like

```
<dl>
    <dt>A title for this link</dt>
    <dd><a href="http://something.linky" rel="noopener noreferrer">http://something.linky</a></dd>
</dl>
```

[Looking at the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/master/en-us/ContentElements/Bullets/Index.html), on this component one should put each description like

```
Term 1|Description 1
Term 2|Description 2
Term 3|Description 3
```

But I'm not sure if is there any way to include links using this schema, or if I have to resort to using the default text component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be possible, when you edit the fluid-Template.

First outsource the default fluid-templates.

Then edit this template:

**Partials/Bullets/Type-2.html**

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" xmlns:ce="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/FluidStyledContent/ViewHelpers" data- namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
 <f:if condition="{bullets}">
   <dl class="ce-bullets">
     <f:for each="{bullets}" as="definitionListItem">
       <f:for each="{definitionListItem}" as="termDescription" iteration="termDescriptionIterator">
        <f:if condition="{termDescriptionIterator.isFirst}">
            <f:then>
                <dt>{termDescription}</dt>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                <dd>{termDescription}</dd>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
     </f:for>
   </f:for>
  </dl>
 </f:if>
</html>
```

Just add a

```
<f:format.html>{termDescription}</f:format.html>
```

around

```
{termDescription}
```

Then you can write this in the description list.

```
Term1 | <LINK 1>Your description</LINK>
Term2 | <a href="http://something.linky" rel="noopener noreferrer">http://something.linky</a>
```